# Unable install requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, pip, command, virtualenv

After cloning a Django application, I went to install the virtual environment in terminal.

I entered the folder and typed: pip install -r requirements.txt

but got the error: -bash: pip: command not found

Comment: How did you create the virtual environment? Or, did you activate it?

Comment: Maybe try `python -m pip -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @SachinKukreja I believe I am activating it. I cloned a Django project and am trying to install the requirements.txt .

Comment: @SachinKukreja I redownloaded pip, tried pip install -r requirements.txt again, and got this error: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement astroid==2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5)
No matching distribution found for astroid==2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))"

Comment: @RobJan when I did that I got Usage:   
  /usr/bin/python -m pip <command> [options]

no such option: -r

Comment: I forget about `install`

Comment: Please check the installation of [astroid](https://pypi.org/project/astroid/) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the `pip` itself which you can install from packaging repository depending on your OS or download (manually or with wget) the and install it using python. This will automatically associate your python version with required pip version. See following commands:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```